# My Django form wont' allow me to save tags

Tags: python, django

I currently have a form on my development site that I use to create new posts. I recently added a Tags model and a tags field in my Post model. I then added the tags field to my form. But when I create a post and select a tag and save it. Everything is saved except for the tag I selected. Heres my code

my models

```
 class Post(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
     title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location,
                               null=True,
                               blank=True,
                               width_field="width_field",
                               height_field="height_field")
     height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
     width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
     content = models.TextField()
     draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     publish = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
     timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
     updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
     tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

     objects = PostManager()

     def __str__(self):
         return self.title

     def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

     class Meta:
         ordering = ["-timestamp", "-updated"]


class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:tag_index", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-timestamp"]
```

my forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Post


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            "title",
            "content",
            "image",
            "draft",
            "publish",
            "tags"
        ]
```

my view

```
def post_create(request):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, "Created !!")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    template = "posts/post_form.html"
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

my post form.html

```
{% extends 'posts/base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        <h1>
            Form
        </h1>


        <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token%}
        {{ form|crispy}}
        <input type="submit" value="Create Post" class="btn btn-default">
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

any and all guidance is welcome

Comment: Note that `commit=False`, which is the cause of your problem, is *completely unnecessary* here.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for the response. I'm following a tutorial why would he pas that argument? What's the reason for "commit=False". thanks for the response tho

Comment: You use it when you want to do something else to the instance before saving it to the db, for instance adding the current user from the request. You're not doing that, so there's no point using it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks I appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to save the many to many field using `save_m2m()`

So basically:

```
instance = form.save(commit=False)
instance.save()
instance.save_m2m()
```

[Excerpt from the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method):

> To work around this problem, every time you save a form using
>   commit=False, Django adds a save_m2m() method to your ModelForm
>   subclass. After you’ve manually saved the instance produced by the
>   form, you can invoke save_m2m() to save the many-to-many form data.

Note that `save_m2m()` is required *only* when you do `commit=False`. If you just do `form.save()`, all data, including the many to many would be saved successfully

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried saving it by adding instance.save_m2m()underneath the way you have it but it gave me this error  AttributeError: 'Post' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'
but if I remove "commit=False" from the way I had it it works

Comment: `save_m2m` is a method on the form, not the model instance.